# Can the "Learn Spell" spell be used to learn high-level item creation spells?

Tags: warlords-battlecry-2

I'm playing [Warlords Battlecry II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warlords_Battlecry_II).

My hero knows the spell *Learn Spell*.  When cast, this spell causes the caster to learn a new spell for the rest of the battle, not restricted to the schools of magic they normally have access to.

My plan was to use this spell to teach myself high-level item creation spells (such as *Create Artifact* or *Rune Item*), then use those spells to give myself better gear.

However, after *many* attempts (I turtled on an easy map, then bound *Learn Spell* to F7 and put a stack of coins on my F7 key for a couple hours), I've only learned the lowest-level item creation spell in the game, *Lesser Item*.  Despite learning nearly every other spell in the game (including the highest-level spells of several schools), I'm still missing *Minor Item*, *Major Item*, *Rune Item*, and *Create Artifact*.

Am I just unlucky, or is there a hardcoded exception in *Learn Spell* to prevent using it to access powerful item creation spells?